# How to inject a child component into a razor generic component like react.js

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, razor

I would like to know if it is possible to create components (Razor / Asp.NET) like the react style. I'll illustrate:

```
<GenericDadContainer>

  <ChildComponentDinamic />

</GenericDadContainer>
```

I want to do this so that my parent containers have dynamicity. They will serve only as containers, and your children need to be dynamic regardless of their models.

If possible I would also like to know if in this context it would be possible to pass parameters to the same besides the child itself.

I understand little of Razor, and I didn't find anything from the internet on a way to reuse the layout better.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same style, but the same idea: in Razor, you can use the so-called "partial views" to divide your page up into "components", and yes, you can pass data to a partial view.

Here is a mini-example:

```
<div class="container">
    @Html.Partial("view-name-here", model)
</div>
```

The `model` variable could be any object you choose.

Read up on partial views in ASP.NET/MVC, for example [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/tips-and-tricks-about-razor-partial-views/).